# Gestionar el cierre de un programa

Tags: java

En mi programa debo gestionar el cierre del mismo desde diferentes sitios (el menú principal, algún formulario, el botón X del la ventana principal...).
Para ello uso este código

```
        // Pide confirmación para salir del programa
        if ( JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir del programa?", "Confirmar salida", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == 0 ){
                // Cierra la conexion con la base de datos, si está activa
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se ha podido desconectar","Desconexión",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }    

            // Salir de la aplicación
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

El problema es que ese código debo repetirlo en varios sitios diferentes, lo cual me parece una perdida de tiempo y recursos importante.
He intentado insertar ese código en el evento *windowClosing* pero no funciona ya que no me muestra el cuadro de confirmación.

¿Donde debería insertar ese código para que controle el cierre del programa desde un único lugar?

Saludos

Comment: Has probado en crearlo en un metodo?
Asi solo llamarias al metodo sin necesidad de reescribir tanto codigo.

Comment: Lo más práctico es un método estático en tu clase principal, la que tiene el main. En programas grandes, donde se organizan bien los backends y frontends, estas clases suelen ser únicamente clases lanzadoras. Tienen únicamente el método main. Como mucho contendrán otros métodos que gestionen los parámetros de entrada si es que el programa está diseñado para poder tenerlos. Y en este tipo de clases pega perfectamente tener un método de finalizar el programa.

Comment: Te animo a dar una respuesta Jesús, considero que puede resolver el problema y aclararle al OP sus dudas.

Comment: @Jesús lo que dijo el we de arriba x2 (porque nunca había oido ese concepto de clases lanzadoras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Como es una clase lanzadora y cuando viene bien utilizarla:**

Pongamos que tenemos una aplicación gráfica divisible. Por ejemplo queremos hacer un office, pero no como aplicaciones diferentes, sino como una misma aplicación que, dependiendo del parámetro de entrada saque un Word, o un Excel. Sin embargo, hay muchos elementos que son comunes, botón copiar, botón pegar, fuentes de letra, estilo de la aplicaación (look and feel). Es por eso que hacer aplicaciones java diferentes sería repetir código. Haciendo una misma aplicación y que dependiendo del parámetro de entrada saque una pantalla de excel o una pantalla de word ahorra código.

¿En qué clase pondríamos el main? No podemos ponerlo en la misma clase del JFrame de word, porque no es lógico tenerla ahí si vamos a trabajar con excel.

Pues en este ejemplo, necesitamos una clase lanzadora. Es una clase que lo único que tiene es un método main que recoge los argumentos de entrada (recordad la declaración del método main):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Tenemos un Array de Strings llamado args. Pues esta clase con sólo 1 método main recogerá los los argumentos, los analizará y dependiendo de estos argumentos instanciará un JFrame de Excel u otro de Word.

A su vez, puede ser que estos JFrame de Excel o Word necesiten algún tipo de preparativo. Como por ejemplo un mismo lookAndFeel que, para no repetirlo en cada uno de los JFrame, puede ser pasado por parámetro además de los parámetros recibidos. Quizás uno de los parámetros pueda ser el archivo que queremos que abra junto con el JFrame.

Pues todas esas cosas puede que sea mejor modularizar el main, sacarlas del main y tener otros métodos "ayudantes" del método main. Y así es como tenemos una clase lanzadora, con un método main que se ayuda de otros métodos para lanzar nuestra App.

Y en esta clase lanzadora del programa cabría también perfectamente un método public de cerrar la app.

A este método se le puede meter por parámetro todo aquello que necesite ser cerrado. Todas las conexiones a servidores SQL, todas las conexiones a sockets, etc. Y este método los cerraría todos (if conexion==abierta... cerrarla) para después hacer ese system.exit(0);

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**

Otro apunte más, es que las conexiones a BBDD no deben de cerrarse al cerrar el programa, sino al dejar de utilizarse. Por ejemplo: Conecto a una BBDD para sacar un listado de clientes. Una vez lo tengo en pantalla, ya no lo necesitaré más. Pues es entonces cuando ha de ser cerrada. Ahora modifico un cliente. Pues vuelvo a abrir conexión, hacer el cambio y cerrarla.

Esto es mucho más efectivo, y consume muchos menos recursos que abrir conexión, traer el listado de clientes, hacer cambios en tabla clientes, cambiar a listado de artículos, hacer cambios en la tabla artículos, cambiar a listado de proveedores... y todo el rato manteniendo la conexión abierta.

Es por eso que cuando se termina una operación, lo mejor es cerrar la conexión en ese momento.

Esta norma puede ser incumplida en situaciones específicas. Por ejemplo, si se tiene una interfaz de añadir o editar clientes desde un archivo, en el que esa interfaz sea la que selecciona el archivo, y tiene los métodos de lectura del archivo y añadir a la BBDD los datos del archivo, es ilógico meter 1 registro, cerrar la conexion, leer del archivo otro registro, abrir conexion, añadir registro, cerrar conexion, leer otro registro del archivo... etc. En ese caso es preferible leer todo el archivo, almacenar en memoria todos los registros del archivo y cerrar el buffer de lectura del archivo. Y después abrir conexion, añadir todos los registros sin cerrar la conexion entre uno y otro, y cuando ya estén todos cerrar la conexion. Pero en las demás situaciones, cuando en una pantalla de consulta termina la consulta (por ejemplo rellenar una tabla) se ha de cerrar la conexión después de terminar la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren de momento dos formas, Clases de Utilidades e Interfaces.

### Clases de utilidades

Las clases de utilidades Tienen esta estructura:

```
public class Utilitaria{

  private Utilitaria(){
   throw new RuntimeException("Esta clase no la instancies papu");
  }

  public static void cerrarALV(){
       // Pide confirmación para salir del programa
        if ( JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir del programa?", "Confirmar salida", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == 0 ){
                // Cierra la conexion con la base de datos, si está activa
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se ha podido desconectar","Desconexión",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }    

            // Salir de la aplicación
            // Y que viva yo, mi apá y la Chona :3
            System.exit(0);
        }
  }
}
```

Hacerlo así te permite llamarla de manera fácil en tus clases<sup>1</sup>:

```
Utilitaria.cerrarALV();
```

Como verás para que una clase se considere de utilidades:

- Todos sus métodos deben de ser estáticos
- Generalmente evitamos que algún distraido la instancie poniéndole un constructor privado

Es considerado un antipatrón, pero son comunes ya que es la forma más natural de implementar algo viniendo de el mundo de la programación imperativa.

Se consideran un antipatrón<sup>2</sup> o mala práctica debido a que:

- Están fuertemente acopladas<sup>3</sup>
- No puedes hacerle un mock de manera natural<sup>4</sup>
- No puedes usar inversón de control con ellas<sup>5</sup>
- Vas a padecer con los proxyes al depurar <sup>6</sup>
- Puede romper la S de los principios de diseño SOLID, que al español significa Responsabilidad única<sup>7</sup>, básicamente quiere decir que es muy fácil que tu equipo al no saber donde poner una funcionalidad fácilmente reusable, las pongas todas en tu clase de utilidades.

### Interfaz

Ahora la segunda forma es una interfaz con una implementación por defecto:

```
public interface PreguntaParaCerrarLaAplicacionALV{
  void default preguntaParaCerrarALV(){
              // Pide confirmación para salir del programa
        if ( JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir del programa?", "Confirmar salida", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == 0 ){
                // Cierra la conexion con la base de datos, si está activa
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se ha podido desconectar","Desconexión",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }    

            // Salir de la aplicación
            // Y que viva yo, mi apá y la Chona :3
            System.exit(0);
        }
  }
}
```

A tu clase se la pones como:

```
public MiVentana extends JFrame implements PreguntaParaCerrarLaAplicacionALV{
```

Y listo paps!, si no deseas cambiar el código te agarra la implementación por defecto, si le haces pruebas unitarias puedes remplazar lo que va a  hacer<sup>8</sup>.

Fuentes:

- [Evita las clases de utilidades (en gringo)](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes/)
- [Las clases estáticas son la morición de la pruebeabilidad (en gringo iwal :'v)](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/)

### Notas

<sup>1</sup> ALV obviamente significa "Adios a La Vida" y no lo que estás pensando groserote

<sup>2</sup> o como dice Perlita en la serie de Roberto Esponja pantalones cuadriformes eso es anticoral

[image: Perlita]

<sup>3</sup> osea que si alguien les mete mano puede afectar gravemente, especialmente si las usas en muchas partes

<sup>4</sup> sí es un concepto rarito de esos de pruebas, testers les llaman, principalmente para pruebas de integración de sistemas y/o capas

<sup>5</sup> y si crees que no es grave porque usas spring checa el siguiente punto relacionado

<sup>6</sup> supongo que on tienes ni idea... con frameworks muy rudos especialmente aquellos que usan reflexión como [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) o [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), posiblemente [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok), AutoValue de Google, creo que igual [guice](/questions/tagged/guice) y seguramente algunas para serializar, como se me ocurre tal vez [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson)

<sup>7</sup> Yo le llamo "si vas a hacer algo hazlo bien y no te desparpajes", o si eres bato "no intentes ser mujer, no trates de hacer varias cosas a la vez en el mismo método no se nos dá :'v"

<sup>8</sup> por ejemplo para que no le haga la morición a tu máquina virtual con el **sexit** (si eres de los eclipsados, **sysexit**) al acabar esa prueba unitaria si faltan otras